# Как отправить на сервер image Base64 или как сохранить его в файл из ionic/cordova?

Tags: javascript, изображения, cordova, base64, ionic

Я пишу приложение на ionicframework.
Сейчас разрабатываю функционал для аватарок пользователей. Сейчас приложение умеет из галереи или камеры получить снимок и с помощью плагина http://www.newupdate.co/ngimgcrop-image-crop-directive-for-angularjs/ обрезать его до аватарки. На выходи получается строка Base64. Теперь мне нужно upload это на сервер либо как есть, т.е. в Base64, либо записать в файл и уже готовый файл отправить на сервер.
При попытке отправить как есть я, видимо, превышаю лимит на длину строки и сервер мой запрос не обрабатывает.

Вопрос №1: как правильно отправлять картинки на сервер в Base64?

Или вопрос №2 для альтернативного варинта: как строку Base64 сохранить в файл?

Comment: Вы отправляете данные в виде base64 для сохранения каким методом ? GET или POST ?

Comment: В АПИ сервера предусмотрен POST. Но можно переписать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел альтернативное решение: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imageResizer .

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо обратить внимание, что если получаете ошибку 414 - слишком длинная строка, то необходимо отправлять данные в *body* post, не в url post.
Отправлять можно base64, на сервере принимать и сохранять как файл, в базу писать ссылку на место на диске сервера.